# Android Facebook : Can we create multiple session in android using facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I want to use multiple session in my application. I am using different ID for different session. But it seems like I can create only one active session in my app.

Is it possible to use multiple facebook session ?

Please help me out

Thanks,
Kinjal Patel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because it keeps itself as a static member var (singleton pattern) so that you can use 
`Session.getActiveSession()`

It's probably possible if you alter the code in session but I couldn't guess what the side affects would be.

I also can't see a good use for this